# setCellValue PhpSpreadsheet the output is not correct

Tags: php, phpexcel, php-7, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

i set setCellValue in my phpspreadsheet 
example

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1'.'3209134102750009');`

and then the output in xlsx when iam already downloaded is 320913410275000**0**

why always replace with **0** at the last?

i tried to changed set format code

```
setFormatCode(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

or `setFormatCode(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER);`

but not working, the output still not correct..
please help..

please don't suggest me to add ' at the first number ('3209134102750009)
cause it make output still have '

Comment: Are you sure you've provided the proper code for that? The given one concatenates `A1` and that long number

Comment: yea sure, btw its not . but , $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','3209134102750009'); btw that just example i put value at A1 but the value '3209134102750009' its correct.

Answer (score 0):

already fixed!!

i add more function after value

```
,PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

so

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('A1','3209134102750009',PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

Thank you